# How to include custom post type comments in buddypress activity feed

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

We have a custom post type "Videos" with comments enabled. I am trying to make the comments for "Videos" show up in the activity feed for Buddypress. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the follow:

```
function record_video_activity( $post_types ) { 
    $post_types[] = 'video'; // Add your custom post type name to the array. 
    return $post_types;
}
add_filter('bp_blogs_record_post_post_types', 'record_video_activity', 1, 1);
add_filter( 'bp_blogs_record_comment_post_types', 'record_video_activity', 10, 1);
```

Comment: I added this to the themes functions.php with no luck. Is there somewhere else I should be putting this? I did a bit of research and found to put it in bp-custom.php but I cannot find that file.

Comment: I have found that you need to create bp-custom.php in the root of your plugins folder. I included your code within that file but the activity is still not being included

Comment: is your custom post type called 'video'? If not, adjust this line: $post_types[] = 'video';

Comment: It is not but I did adjust that to match my custom post type. Is this solution working for you?